# get a default value when variable is unset in make

Tags: bash, gnu-make, variable-expansion

(edit: question more accurate based on @Michael feedback)

In bash, I often use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): the following commands print "`default value`" when `$VARNAME` is unset, otherwise it prints the VARNAME content.

```
echo ${VARNAME:-default value}  #if VARNAME empty => print "default value" 
echo ${VARNAME-default value}   #if VARNAME empty => print "" (VARNAME string)
```

I [did not find](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) a similar feature on GNU `make`.
I finally wrote in my `Makefile`:

```
VARNAME ?= "default value"
all:
        echo ${VARNAME}
```

But I am not happy with this solution: it always creates the variable `VARNAME` and this may change the behavior on some makefiles.

**Is there a simpler way to get a default value on unset variable?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to use the expansion of a GNU make variable if it is non-empty and a default value if it is empty, but not set the variable, you can do something like this:

```
all:
        echo $(or $(VARNAME),default value)
```

Comment: Just to be anally complete, the make version of bash's `${VARNAME-default}` (no `:`) is `$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin VARNAME),default,${VARNAME})`. (Appologgies if I've typed that wrongly.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a variable has a non-empty value, you can use:

```
ifeq ($(VARNAME),)
        VARNAME="default value"
else
        do_something_else
endif
```

For checking if a variable has been defined or not, use `ifdef`.

Refer to [Syntax of Conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) in the manual for more.

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible solution, but not as simple as `VARNAME ?= "default value"` (note: I do not want to create/change variable `VARNAME`). Cheers

Comment: The snippet mentioned above doesn't create/change `VARNAME`.  It simply checks whether it has a non-empty value & would evaluate to false (1) whether `VARNAME` exists or not, or (2) if `VARNAME` is empty.  In either case, it wouldn't create `VARNAME`.  You can use `ifdef ($(VARNAME))` later to verify!

Comment: oops, you are right, my apologies. I was looking for something more convenient to use (like @MadScientist's answer). I wanted to tell you that I prefer to use `VARNAME ?= "default value"` (even if it creates a variable) than the above 5-lines-snippet (my point of view). I give you +1 because your solution is correct. I you think @MadScientist's answer is good, please give him +1 also ;-) Thank you for your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case where the result of filtering a shell command could be a single word or empty string. When empty, it should fallback to the default word. In the example below APPLE_LINUX will be 'apple' on macOS or 'linux' on other platforms. MSG will be set to the message for the appropriate platform. The example intentionality avoids using `ifeq`.

```
MACHINE         := $(shell $(COMPILE.cpp) -dumpmachine)
MACHINE_APPLE   := $(findstring apple,$(MACHINE))
APPLE_LINUX     := $(firstword $(MACHINE_APPLE) linux)
apple.MSG       := You are building on macOS
linux.MSG       := You are building on Linux or another OS
MSG             := $($(APPLE_LINUX).MSG)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the colon.  If you use `:-` in your substitution the default value will be used if the variable is null, an empty string or it does not exist, but just using `-` on its own will only substitute the default value if the variable has not been defined.

```
# var1=default
# var2=

# echo var2 is ${var2:-$var1}
var2 is something
# echo var3 is ${var3:-$var1}
var3 is something

# echo var2 is ${var2-$var1}
var2 is
# echo var3 is ${var3-$var1}
var3 is something
```

Comment: Thank you for the distinction between `:-` and `-`. I edit my question to be more accurate. But your answer is for shell, it does not work for makefile...