# How can I define the default value for a variable in mkfile

Tags: shell, plan-9, rc-shell

Makefile:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME?=$HOME/.config
```

I want convert the line to Plan9 mkfile syntax.

I tried

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=`{if(~ $XDG_CONFIG_HOME '') echo $HOME/.config; if not echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME}
```

and it worked but it's ugly. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*mk*(1) doesn’t provide such a built-in way of defining variables only if they aren’t non-empty environment variables. Actually, neither any *make*(1) from Bell Labs nor POSIX *make*(1) provide such a way to do that, the `?=` syntax is just a GNU extension.

What you usually would do is in your `mkfile` just set the variable normally:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME = $home/.config
```

and overwrite the variable in the *mk*(1) command:

```
    ; mk 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME='^$home^'/cfg'
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell, ":-" is used to set a variable to a default value in case the variable has no value:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}
```

Comment: maybe this is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035247/get-a-default-value-when-variable-is-unset-in-make